# Issue with this Search Algorithm C#

Tags: c#

I have created Search algorithm to search any string in the Text.I just want the count of matches returned and want to search by only one key. I have tested the performance by searching single character 'a' in file of size 2 mb and it takes around 7 seconds.Can you please suggest better algorithm or if i am missing anything here.

```
   public int SearchText(string fromString,string searchText,bool isCaseSensitive)
       {
           int searchTextLength=searchText.Length;
           if (!isCaseSensitive)
           {
               fromString = fromString.ToLower();
               searchText = searchText.ToLower();
           }
            int matchCount=0;
            while (fromString.Length > searchText.Length)
            {
                int firstMatchIndex=fromString.IndexOf(searchText[0]);
                if (firstMatchIndex > -1)
                {
                    if (searchText == fromString.Substring(firstMatchIndex, searchTextLength))
                        matchCount++;
                    fromString = fromString.Remove(0, firstMatchIndex + searchTextLength);
                }
                else
                    break;
            }
            return matchCount;
       }
```

Comment: Why didnt you used string.contains() ... ?????

Comment: Because i needed the count also

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are creating unnecessary temporary strings all over the place. You can change it to something like this.. which *should* be faster:

```
public int SearchText(string fromString, string searchText, bool isCaseSensitive) {
    int matchCount = 0;

    var comparison = isCaseSensitive
        ? StringComparison.InvariantCulture
        : StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase;

    int foundIndex = fromString.IndexOf(searchText,
        comparison);

    while (foundIndex > -1) {
        foundIndex = fromString.IndexOf(searchText,
            foundIndex + 1,
            comparison);

        matchCount++;
    }

    return matchCount;
}
```

EDIT: I tested this. It takes **197ms to process 2MB of randomized data**.

Comment: Thanks you!!You are right. I have checked your code with same input and indeed it takes less than a second.I should have just checked full text using IndexOf and not one character first. I think i was lost somewhere while writing the code.

Answer (score 1):

Try using regular expressions

```
public int SearchText(string fromString, string searchText, bool isCaseSensitive)
{
        RegexOptions options = isCaseSensitive ? 
            RegexOptions.None : RegexOptions.IgnoreCase;
        return Regex.Matches(fromString, Regex.Escape(searchText), options).Count;
}
```

**EDIT** I tested this in LinqPad, and it takes 113 ms to get the count from 2.5 MB of Lorem Ipsum.

Comment: Remember to escape the input, otherwise it may produce unexpected output.

Comment: Thank you for your alternate approach. I always tend to overlook Regex's power. TEsted it too and it take around 60-80ms similar to that of approach suggested by simon which in range of (50-70 ms). Tested by executing both the approaches 10 times.